# exception when enabling solr repositories in solr kafka integration

Tags: java, solr, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to solr and trying to save data read from kafka topic. When I am tying to do `@EnableSolrRepositories` I am getting following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDocRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

**EDITED:**
this is my repository

```
@Component
@Repository
public interface MyDocRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Assert, String> {

}
```

My config class contains both kafka and solr configs

```
    @Configuration
@EnableKafka
@Component
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackageClasses = MyDocRepository.class)
public class ReceiverConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.servers.bootstrap}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${solr.server.url}")
    private String solrUrl;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        System.out.println("consumer configs : ");
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections
        // to the Kakfa cluster
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        // consumer groups allow a pool of processes to divide the work of
        // consuming and processing records
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "helloworld");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        System.out.println("consumer factory");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        System.out.println("kafka listerner configs");
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory
                = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Receiver receiver() {
        System.out.println("consumer receiver");
        return new Receiver();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSolrClientFactoryBean solrServerFactoryBean() {
        HttpSolrClientFactoryBean factory = new HttpSolrClientFactoryBean();
        System.out.println(solrUrl);
        factory.setUrl(solrUrl);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactoryBean().getObject());
    }
}
```

my receiver class for kafka

```
public class Receiver {

    @Autowired
    private IndexServiceImpl indexServiceImpl;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.helloworld}")
    public void receive(String message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("started");
        LOGGER.info("received message='{}'", message);
        latch.countDown();
        Assert assertObj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(message, Assert.class);
        indexServiceImpl.save(assertObj);
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }
}
```

my service class

```
@Component
@Service
public class IndexServiceImpl implements IndexService {

    @Autowired
    MyDocRepository myDocRepository;

    @Override
    public String save(Assert term) {
        myDocRepository.save(term);
        return "success";
    }

}
```

can anyone help me solving this issue.

Comment: Add some source codes please. We see the trace but no code and we can't help you in this case.

Comment: i have edited my question please check. If anything missing remind me @M.Situation